# How to do a MaxBy in RavenDb MapReduce

Tags: mapreduce, ravendb

Using the `Northwind` database from RavenDB tutorial I'm trying to group orders by employee and get the most resent order for every employee.

Map:

```
from order in docs.Orders
select new {
    Employee = order.Employee,
    Count = 1,
    MostRecent = order.OrderedAt,
    MostRecentOrderId = order.Id
}
```

Reduce with nonexisting MaxBy:

```
from result in results
group result by result.Employee into grp
select new {
    Employee = grp.Key,
    Count = grp.Sum(result => result.Count),
    MostRecent = grp.Max(result => result.MostRecent),
    MostRecentOrderId = grp.MaxBy(result => result.MostRecent).MostRecentOrderId,
}
```

Reduce attempt:

```
from result in results
group result by result.Employee into grp
let TempMostRecent = grp.Max(result => result.MostRecent)
select new {
    Employee = grp.Key,
    Count = grp.Sum(result => result.Count),
    MostRecent = TempMostRecent,
    MostRecentOrderId = grp.First(result => result.MostRecent == TempMostRecent).MostRecentOrderId
}
```

However my reduce attempt returns 0 results.

Also: will RavenDB treat the `Order.OrderetAt` as a proper `DateTime` value and order them correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it like

```
from order in docs.Orders
select new {
    Employee = order.Employee,
    Count = 1,
    MostRecent = order.OrderedAt,
    MostRecentOrderId = order.Id
}

from result in results
group result by result.Employee into grp
let maxOrder = grp.OrderByDescending(x=>x.MostRecent).First()
select new {
    Employee = grp.Key,
    Count = grp.Sum(result => result.Count),
    MostRecent = maxOrder.MostRecent,
    MostRecentOrderId = maxOrder.MostRecentOrderId,
}
```

Comment: 1. thank you - it works. 2. Now I see that my Reduce produces errors, however I don't understad the reason. The `TempMostRecent` is an `IComperable`, and I think it should be a `System.DateTime`, why is it a `IComperable`?

Comment: On the server side, dates are held as strings, maybe this is related?